# Remove method in Red Black Tree

Tags: red-black-tree, remove-method

I have problem with the remove method in a RB tree. There is a NullPointerException at `x.parent=y.parent`. The problem is definitely `x=null`, and if I use this x in method DeleteFixUp there is NullPointerException too. Where do I have a mistake?

```
Element delete(Element DeleteNode)   
 {

Element x=null;

Element y=null;

    if((DeleteNode.left==null)||(DeleteNode.right==null))
        y=DeleteNode;
    else 
        y=Succesor(DeleteNode,root);

    if (y.left != null)
        x=y.left;
    else 
        x=y.right;

    x.parent=y.parent;

    if (y.parent == null)
        root = x;
    else 
    if (y == y.parent.left)
        y.parent.left = x;
    else 
        y.parent.right = x;
    if (y != DeleteNode)
        DeleteNode.value = y.value;

    if(!isRed(y))
    { DeleteFixUp(x);}
    return y;
}
```

And here is Successor method:

```
 Element Succesor(Element x, Element root)

 {

    if( x.right != null )
    { x=FindMin(x.right);
        return x;
              }

    Element succ = null;

    while (root != null)
    {
        if (_comparator.compare(x.value,root.value)==-1)
        {
            succ = root;
            root = root.left;
        }
        else if ((_comparator.compare(x.value,root.value)==1))
            root = root.right;
        else
            break;
    }

    return succ;
}
```

Okey, I have solved this problem, but I have another one.
I add to my code:

```
Element delete(Element DeleteNode)   
 {

Element x=null;

Element y=null;

    if((DeleteNode.left==null)||(DeleteNode.right==null))
        y=DeleteNode;
    else 
        y=Succesor(DeleteNode,root);

    if (y.left != null)
        x=y.left;
    else 
        x=y.right;
    //added to code 
    if (x == null) 
    {x = new Element(null);              
     x.kolor=0;          
    }


    x.parent=y.parent;

    if (y.parent == null)
        root = x;
    else 
    if (y == y.parent.left)
        y.parent.left = x;
    else 
        y.parent.right = x;
    if (y != DeleteNode)
        DeleteNode.value = y.value;

    if(!isRed(y))
    { DeleteFixUp(x);}
    return y;
}
```

Now, I have a question, how to remove this `x.value=null`, after delete?

Answer (score 0):

The node you are deleting may not have any children. In this case you have no subtree to reparent.